# Why does `websocket.close()` before connection establishes triggers `onerror`?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Calling `websocket.close()` before connection is established triggers `onerror`. I wasn't able to figure out what the error is, nor where it came from.

```
const connection = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
connection.onopen = () => {
    console.log('open');
}
connection.onerror = (error) => {
    throw error; // this is thrown
}
connection.close();
```

Tested in chrome dev console. `onerror` is being triggered when `close` is called.

If I wait until the connection is established before calling `close`, no error is thrown. I wonder what the error is

Edit:
included the error output:
[image]

Comment: can you console.log the error and show us the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took my own advice and checked it out - and it gave me this:
[image: error]

Not sure if that answers your question if I say that it's more strange *not* to expect an error when you're not waiting for a connection before closing a socket.

Just handle it with a try-catch or put your `connection.close()` inside your `onopen` handler?

Comment: not sure if that's an option unfortunately - threading and synchronous operation is messy in javascript. I still haven't got it all worked out but from what I know javascript is designed to be a single-threaded language. if someone could post a relevant link i'd be grateful :3

Comment: oh, now I see the yellow text. I was wondering if closing before connection establishment is forbidden. I guess this answers my question.